# Changing Background in multiple kivymd windows

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to create a kivymd app which has two windows. The second window consists of a file chooser. The file chooser have white font when displaying the names of the files and folders. So I decided to change the background of the second window(if not possible , then all the windows). But when I tried the way written in the documentation, only the first window is changing color. Please help me. Any answers are welcomed.

Comment: How are you making two windows? Since Kivy only supports one per process, presumably you're setting the value for the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you mean screens (when you say Window - or do you mean Window - as inclement pointed out Kivy only supports one per process).

Try the following:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

...

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1) # Call this BEFORE calling MainApp().run()
MainApp().run()
```

Does this solve your problem?